# Scheduling Appointments for iPhone Repair at the Apple Store?

Tags: repair, apple-store

In our IT department we have two iPhones 5 with cracked screens and we need to get them fixed.

I've gone to the Apple Store personally for my iPod Touch 4G, and I was required to schedule an appointment at the Genius Bar.

Does this work the same way for businesses?  I found the [Apple Store in question](http://www.apple.com/retail/shadyside/) on their website, and there's a space to `Make a reservation` at the Genius Bar, but there is also `Access Member Services` which I didn't see the last time I scheduled an appointment.

Does scheduling an appointment for a business differ from scheduling a personal appointment to fix an Apple device?  Also, can they fix it the same day, or ship the repaired product back to you?

I saw a video on replacing the screen of an iPhone 5 and it doesn't look that difficult provided you have the right tools.  However the screens we ordered online didn't work, so that is why we are reverting to the Apple Store.

Comment: You could just call the store and ask them.

Comment: I did call the store.  They directed me to their phone-bot and I left a message and was not yet called back.  Any idea how long it takes them?

Comment: Ah there's a business button on the Genius Bar scheduling thing.  Didn't see that last time.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options within Apple's eco system.

The first is Joint Venture, a program that gives priority service to business customers both over the phone and in store.  With Mac repairs this also allows for a loaner if needed for the duration of the repair.  You can read more about Joint Venture at [Apple's business page](http://www.apple.com/retail/business/).  It IS a paid, subscription, service but depending on your needs it could be helpful.

The second would be to look into their [iOS Direct Service Program](http://www.apple.com/support/programs/ids/).  Essentially entering into the program allows you to train your IT staff to properly diagnose iOS devices in accordance with Apple's guidelines and setup service on them directly, without dealing with AppleCare/Genius Bar.  It's a free service but your organization will need to set up normal credit/billing info with Apple and jump through an application process to enroll.

The third option is creating a mail in repair with AppleCare.  They can provide a quote over the phone and send you a prepaid box to ship the phone in to them.  Shipping is overnight each way (one night to get the box to you, one night for the phone to reach them, another night to come back to you) and included at no additional charge.  This is true for warranty and non warranty repairs.

With all of that said... I typically take our damaged devices into the Genius Bar by [scheduling online](http://concierge.apple.com/reservation/us/en/) ahead of time.  An appointment IS required, however if you show up without an appointment they can often squeeze you in within an hour. They'll provide a free quote and if the part is in stock offer to repair it at that time if you agree to the cost.  If nothing else it gets you out of the office for an hour!  If I were in your shoes I would do this.  By checking the "business related" box in the reservation system you should end up with a member of the business team coming out to tell you about Joint Venture.  If they don't you can always ask the Genius or Concierge about meeting with a member of the Business team to discuss exactly how Joint Venture could help in situations like this.